# How does startForeground affect threads started in an android service?

Tags: android, service, foreground

If you have a long running program that's being run as a service, you're supposed to fire off a thread to do the work, because the service runs in the main application's thread.
What I don't get, is that you can mark the service important by saying "startForeground()" but that trait is tied to the service (presumably service object) and has nothing to do with threads.

How does this trait affect the longevity of a thread started in the service's onStartCommand call?

What I'm getting at is, how does android know not to kill that thread, since it's not the thread being flagged as foreground, but the service that's being flagged.
What if I start 5 threads? I can't find any documentation that explains the relationship between the foreground-ness of a service and the priority of the threads that service spawns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because the service runs in the main application's thread

Objects do not run on threads in Java. Methods do. The lifecycle methods of a service (e.g., `onStartCommand()`) are called on the main application thread.

> How does this trait affect the longevity of a thread started in the service's onStartCommand call?

`startForeground()` makes it less likely that Android will automatically terminate your process due to old age, low memory conditions, and so forth.

> how does android know not to kill that thread

Android does not kill threads on its own. Android terminates processes on its own.

> What if I start 5 threads?

Then you start 5 threads.

> I can't find any documentation that explains the relationship between the foreground-ness of a service and the priority of the threads that service spawns.

They have nothing to do with each other. You will not find any documentation that explains the relationship between "the foreground-ness of a service" and the quantity of hair of Android book authors, either.

Also, you seem to be conflating longevity and priority with respect to threads, and these have nothing to do with one another either, though that's more a Java thing than an Android thing.

Comment: ahhh the key point you make there is Android terminates processes on its own. I thought it would kill just the service not the entire application. So what you're really doing is flagging the entire application as important, not just the service.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you, because that makes more sense, but this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html mentions the service specifically. but it also says: Other application components running in the same process as the service (such as an Activity) can, of course, increase the importance of the overall process beyond just the importance of the service itself. Which lends favor to your point about the killing applying to the process as a whole.